# Facebook iOS SDK Dialog parameters

Tags: facebook, ipad, ios

This is probably a n00b question, but nontheless... I have a bit of a problem using the Facebook SDK in my iPad app: when I display a dialog using `[facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];` I don't see any way I can change the title, the content or the URL of what I want to share.

In their Demo App, Facebook has the following code:

```
- (IBAction)publishStream:(id)sender {

  SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

  NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary 
  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",
                                @"href", nil], nil];

  NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
  NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"a long run", @"name",
                               @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                               @"it is fun", @"description",
                               @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];
  NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
  NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary
                                 dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                 actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                 attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                 nil];


  [_facebook dialog:@"feed"
          andParams:params
        andDelegate:self];

}
```

However, when I press the publishStream button, none of those strings shows on the dialog! :S

Is there something I'm not doing right? all I changed in that Demo App was the Facebook kAppId and the URL Scheme.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
This is the solution I found: change your code in this way:

```
[_facebook dialog:@"stream.publish"
         andParams:params
         andDelegate:self];
```

use stream.publish and not feed.

Comment: awesome, thanks! how did you find out you needed stream.publish and not feed?

Comment: Hmm. When I try this, the Facebook dialog comes back and declares "h" is not allowed ... whatever h is. :(

Comment: As @MrRogers noted, the stream.publish API is deprecated. You should follow his [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610153/facebook-ios-sdk-dialog-parameters/6739887#6739887) instead.

Comment: @dbfranz: this is outdated. no longer working. follow Mr Rogers's answer instead.

Answer (score 30):

I realized this is already answered, but I found this to be the correct answer.  It follows what FB has [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).  The image and/or link actually shows up in the dialog.  `stream.publish` didn't make that change for me.  Also, the [dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) page says that the `stream.publish` is old.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                               @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                               @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                               @"Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for apps to interact with users.", @"description",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
                               nil];


[_facebook dialog:@"feed"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Stream.publish is dated.  Feed is correct, but the example is wrong.

Comment: Dialog shows up, but the message is empty. Docs says that 'message' field is ignored now: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Silly that they don't update the examples for that.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @MrRogers, I have a related (but not identical) question to which I think you might know the answer.  Would you mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993457/posting-to-facebook-feed-from-iphone-what-do-i-need-to-instantiate-for-this-to ?

Comment: Can I use an UIImage instead of a HTTP url for the picture?

Comment: @Quakeboy, no you can't.  My understanding is that you'd need to post the image separately.  You can check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/11501388/3965

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I haven't worked with the sample app, but I would think that you would need to do a POST if you want to post something to the wall. Check out this question and my answer here: [Post to user's Facebook wall with iPhone using latest FBConnect SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486528/post-to-users-facebook-wall-with-iphone-using-latest-fbconnect-sdk/4487523#4487523)

To summarize, here is the method I used:

```
- (void)requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)graphPath
                   andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
               andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod
                 andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate;
```

like this:

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[user_id]/feed" 
                          andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test wall post" forKey:@"message"]
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];
```

to post a comment to `[user_id]`'s wall.

Comment: The question as using `dialog:` not the background `requestWithGraphPath:` method.