# How to post local image with dialog text in facebook

Tags: facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I have upload images with url image successful on this way

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                               @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                               @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                               @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
                               nil];

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
           andParams:params
         andDelegate:self];
```

Now i want to upload image from a local image in same way

like

```
    profImg = [UIImage imageNamed:LoginWithFacebookNormal@2x.png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(profImg)];
```

i have used **data, @"picture",** in dictionary but it's give me error

**is it any other way to upload local/Gallery/resource image with dialog box + comment area ?**

I have searched but every time found that only url image can feed the dialog box

I have used Hackgraph tutorial for this posting.

**Note: I am not using Sharekit or any other API i have used only Graph API**

Comment: Hey, I am in a similar situation, I want to post an image through a dialog (in order to allow the user to set some text), but all dialog options I have found requires a link instead of raw data.
Did u found any solution or workaround?

Comment: @AMGG nop still waiting for answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after lots of research I get the example of Facebook. Download the example from [here](https://github.com/hiren443/ASFBPostController). You have to make modification because currently example hold static image.

Comment: i just tested, this method works great! it is interesting that the comment for requestWithGraphPath clearly states that "Note that binary data parameters (e.g. pictures) are not yet supported by this helper function.", but yet posting a local image using this method still works.