# iPhone - Facebook post to a friend's wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-wall

I am working on an application on facebook integration.
I don't know how to post on a friends wall or if this is possible.

Or at least to send his friends a message.

Can anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a similar related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486528/post-to-users-facebook-wall-with-iphone-using-latest-fbconnect-sdk) about posting to facebook wall (unfortunately that was the case for the user him/herself only). I was thinking that you might be able to modify the graph path to use a friend's user_id instead of your own, in the fragment:-

```
...requestWithGraphPath:@"[user_id]/feed"...
```

Need to first test it out to verify this, but this seems like an option to me.

Comment: I will test it tomorrow and will let you know if this is working.
Thank you a lot.