# Issue with Facebook feed dialog

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I'm trying implement a Facebook dialog feed, but it doesn't show anything. I have followed :

[Post to user's Facebook wall with iPhone using latest FBConnect SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486528/post-to-users-facebook-wall-with-iphone-using-latest-fbconnect-sdk/4487523#4487523)

and:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Here is my code:

```
 -(void) facebookPost{


    NSString *kAppId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"383032031757454"];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   kAppId, @"app_id",
                                   @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                                   @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                                   @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
                                   nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Froi

Answer (score 0):

i think u have to set accessToken like below

```
[params setObject:facebook.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got this error when I add your line : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: access_token)'. Do I need some previous work to solve it?